# Automatically generate html file from an erb file using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a RoR app that tracks the status of values in a database and displays the visualization of this information in the form of charts, graphs, and tables generated by an erb file. This is very handy and I am able to save snapshots of the status' of the DBs by simply saving the page when I open it in a browser. What I would like, however, is for my app to automatically do this saving for me on a nightly basis. I assume this is possible but I'm not having much luck with this so far. Any suggestion on this point would be very helpful.

Comment: are these charts and graphs generated dynamically from the single HTML? if they are separate files then solution will be more complicated because you will have to save more files

Comment: Yes they are, I have graphs that are built using google's chart tools. I simply have the url's in the erb file and I fill out the important bits with information pulled from the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *whenever*: https://github.com/javan/whenever

From the readme:

> Whenever is a Ruby gem that provides a
>   clear syntax for writing and deploying
>   cron jobs.

There is also *delayed-job*: https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job

From the Readme:

> Delayed_job (or DJ) encapsulates the
>   common pattern of asynchronously
>   executing longer tasks in the
>   background.

Comment: Ultimately ended out writing straight-up cron jobs in the manner expected by the Heroku cron add-on. (http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cron) Looking at my posting I now see that I didn't mention that I was deploying to Heroku at all, oops. Whenever worked well for our internal testing though.

Answer (score 1):

you can always use `render_to_string` method to render your erb. For example you need to render `show.html.erb` for show action in `statistics` controller:

```
 my_page = render_to_string :controller => 'statistics', :action => 'show', :layout => 'application'
```

but firstly you should define all it's variables which you use int show view.

```
@data = Data.last_data
@users = User.active
enter code here
my_page = render_to_string :controller => 'statistics', :action => 'show', :layout => 'application'
snapshot = Snapshot.new :page => my_page
snapshot.save
```

API: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render_to_string

Comment: This does not work anymore. render_to_string is defined in ActionController::Base. Since the class/module is defined outside the scope of the Rails controllers the function is not available.